# 11.04 loses WAN but not LAN connectivity

Tags: 11.04, networking, internet-connection

At apparently decreasing intervals my 11.04 system loses WAN (outside internet) connectivity. Its hardware connection is via a wireless adapter which connects to the system via ethernet; thus the system sees an ethernet connection.  When the problem occurs, there is no loss of connection to other hosts on the LAN, and another host on the LAN has WAN connectivity. Rebooting the 11.04 system cures the problem, at least for a while.

In the problem state:

ping www.apple.com --(from 11.04 system) produces no output

ping www.apple.com --(from Mac OS system on the LAN) produces normal output

ping 192.168.168.1xx --(from 11.04; IP=another host on LAN) produces normal output

ping 192.168.168.1 --(from 11.04; IP=router's LAN address) produces no output

my usual way of communicating with the 11.04 system, ssh from another host on the LAN, continues to operate normally

11.04 Chromium Browser just spins the mouse pointer when attempting to contact www.google.com

ifconfig looks OK

netstat -r looks OK

It's AS IF the router suddenly decides to block WAN access by the problem system.

Ideas or suggestions for diagnosing?

Answer (score 2):

While it's bizarre to me, as I know nothing about hardware other than that electrons are yellow:  there's pretty good circumstantial evidence that the problem was caused by a voltage drop on the electrical circuit that the router is plugged into.  I noticed *momentary* networking delays elsewhere on the LAN coincident with such drops, but the problem with the 11.04 system, which persisted until rebooting it, is the only non-transient symptom that I noticed.

I'm guessing rebooting cured the problem because it renewed the (DHCP) connection with the router.